# how to repopulate/recreate autoincrement in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to know if I can repopulate the autoincrement value in mysql.

Because, I have records that look similar:

```
ID Name
1  POP
3  OLO
12 lku
```

Basically , I want a way to update the ID to this

```
ID Name
1  POP
2  OLO
3  lku
```

Is there any way to do this in mysql?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not best practice to fiddle your primary keys - better to let your DB handle it itself. There can be issues if, in between the `UPDATE` and `ALTER`, another record is added. Because of this, you must `LOCK` the table, which might hang other queries and spike load on a busy production server.

```
LOCK TABLES table WRITE
UPDATE table SET id=3 WHERE id=12;
ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
UNLOCK TABLES
```

OR - for thousands of rows (with no foriegn key dependencies):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nameTemp( name varchar(128) not null )
INSERT INTO name SELECT name FROM firstTable
TRUNCATE firstTable
INSERT INTO firstTable SELECT name FROM nameTemp
```

The latter method will only work where you have no foreign keys. If you do, you'll require a lookup table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lookup( newId INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, oldId INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY newId( newId ) );
INSERT INTO lookup (oldId) SELECT id FROM firstTable
[do temp table queries above]
```

You now have a `lookup` table with the old to new ids which you can use to update the foreign key dependencies on your other tables (on a test server!)

Comment: NO, I have thousands of records that I want to repopulate for, This data is just sample.

Comment: Updated for thousands of records

Answer (score 1):

Changing the primary key is a *very* bad idea as it endangers your referential integrity (what if another table uses the id without having a foreign key with proper "on change"?).

If you really, really have to do it and don't care about bad side-effects:

- Create a second table with identical structure
- INSERT INTO new_table (id, [other fields]) SELECT NULL, [other fields] FROM old_table;
- DROP old_table;
- RENAME new_table old_table;

Warning:
This will damage every other table that has foreign keys on this table (but if you had such then you wouldn't be doing this anyways).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like...

```
Create Temporary table MyBackup
(  ID as your autoincrement,
   OldID as Int for backlinking/retention,
   RestOfFields as their type )

insert into MyBackup
(    OldID
     RestOfFields )
select 
     ID as OldID,
     RestOfFields
  from
     YourOriginalTable
  order by
     ID  (this is your original ID)
```

Then you'll have a new table with an autoincrement with new IDs assigned, yet have a full copy of their original ID.  Then, you can do correlated updates against other tables and set the ID = ID where ID = OldID.  By keeping your insert via order by the original ID, it will keep the numbers from replacing out of sequence..  Ex: if your table was orderd as 
Old ID = 3, new ID = 1
Old ID = 1, new ID = 3
Old ID = 12, new ID = 2

Your old 3's will become 1's, then the 1's would become 3's, and 12's become 2's

Old ID = 1, new ID = 1
Old ID = 3, new ID = 2
Old ID = 12, new ID = 3

your 3's won't overwrite the higher number, and the 12's won't conflict with the 3's since the threes were already lowered to 2's.